# Email layout not full-width with Outlook app and Gmail app iOS

Tags: html, phpmailer, html-email

I have been trying to get the email layout full-width.

I tried:

1. Put every table and body,html on width:100% max-width:100%;min-width:100%;.
2. Tried also making the max-width and min-width the WIDTH size of my iPhone 7.
3. Tried changing my body to position:absolute or fixed.
4. Also tried adding `<meta>`.

Read everything about it on Stack Overflow and other websites.

How can I fix this?

```
                     <!DOCTYPE html>
                     <html>
                     <head>
                     </head>

                     <body class="body">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="color:#FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#71aee8">
                     <tr>
                       <td>
                         <b>Email test</b>
                       </td>
                     </tr>
                   </table>
                           </body>
                           </html>
```

This above email layout returns a blue table but I can not seem to make it full width.

Need it to work on Outlook app and Gmail app IOS. On my iPhone mail app it does work to make it full-width.

Comment: Remove the table. It serves no purpose as you have one single cell. Change it to `<div style="color: #FFFFFF; background: "#71aee8"></div>` and you'll have full width. The clients you mentioned as far as I know supports inline css.

Comment: @Onimusha I normally have alot of cells and tables inside this email layout. This is just a example. But i will try it. Will let you know thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: Got it. In that case you should try with div to do layout. Modern email clients handle it well. I had to remove tables from 5 email templates from a recent job because outlook displayed them narrow on the left. I replaced it with DIV and CSS and it sorted the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the width of an element will be dependent on the content within it. That is, even if the width is set to 100%, if 100% is 200px wide, it will only fill 200px. So make sure you have enough content to fill the page in testing.

For a 100% width that works across all email clients:

```
<body style="margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#eaeaeb;">
    <center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#eaeaeb;">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="100%" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;" bgcolor="#eaeaeb" >
        <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;" >
        <![endif]-->
         <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </center>
    <!-- END OUTER WRAPPER -->
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and time. I put a `<p>` inside CONTENT HERE. And it still show's the grey color from you not in full-width(10/20px on each side). Same output as before. Tested in Outlook mail IOS and Gmail IOS.

Comment: Oh okay -- yes there is a white border on some email clients which is not possible to overwrite. (Best to show us exactly via a screenshot if possible)

Comment: The weird thing is that Apple IOS Mail was FULL-WIDTH. But i bought a new Iphone 11 and the IOS MAIL from APPLE is now ALSO with space from left and right like 10/15px on each side LOL. Hahaha I gave up and just leave it like this, i need to continue with the rest of the code. Thanks for your answer and time.